# How to get unique year values from created_at?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a collection called `$products`, each instance of which has a field `created_at`. The latter obviously has a format `('Y-m-d H:i:s')` in the DB. Now, it's easy to get instances with unique `created_at`. However, I'd like to retrieve unique **year values** of `created_at` in *one single expression* (that I can write in my view). What I am looking for is:

```
$products->unique( year value ('Y' ONLY) of 'created_at' )
```

This expression should evaluate to something like this: `['2012', '2013', '2016']`.

Comment: have you tried `$unique = $products->unique(function ($item) {
    return $item['created_at']->year;
});`

Comment: @Angad Dubey Looks hacky, but would work for my example ;) Wish I could use native PHP date method(s) though or something similar

Comment: That's right Angad, ¿why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Building on the comment that gives you a collection with unique timestamps, you can map out the year and sort with the following code.

```
$years = $products->unique(function($item){
    return $item['created_at']->year;
})->map(function($item){
    return $item['created_at']->year;
})->sort()->toArray();
```

Comment: Why don't you use map() first before unique()? It isn't make the script more efficient? `$users = User::all(); $users = $users->map(function($user){ return $user['created_at']->year; })->unique()->sort()->toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tim result

```
$products = DB::table('products')->get();

$years = $products->unique(function($item){
          return $item['created_at']->year;
         })->map(function($item){
          return $item['created_at']->year; 
         })->sort()->toArray();
```

You can use toArray or values() to get the result of collection